# SnappyData - configuring streaming job spark settings

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, snappydata

I can see how to configure a SparkConf when creating a streaming application ([see here](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappy-poc/blob/6bb69c75ebe4911273bcd0eadb9cc9669bcb2a7b/src/main/scala/io/snappydata/benchmark/KafkaSnappyIngestionPerf.scala))

I assume that I can configure the SparkConf through the SnappyStreamingContext for a streaming job similar to a streaming application. Let's say I get a handle to the SparkConf in a streaming job and modify some settings. Do these settings only apply to this streaming job or is this a global configuration update for all jobs?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the SparkConf through the SnappyStreamingContext for a streaming job, and it is same as spark streaming configuration. Since SparkConf is a global configuration it is applicable to all the jobs in a streaming application. I think Spark doesn't allow you to change SparkConf after starting your application.